# Do I need to fill the "Part-3 processing information" of form I-539 if I am changing status from F1 to J2?

Tags: visa, j-visa

I am changing my status from F1 to J2 and filling I-538 form, I have confusion in some points

What data should I put here.

```
I-539, Part 2. 
    3b. New status and affective date of change.
```

Do I need to fill Part 3 if yes what should I put here.

```
 I-539 Part 3. 
             1.I request that my requested status be extended until
```